# Why WCF service can't send exact exception to client without fault exception?

Tags: c#, wcf

Please let me know why we can't get exact exception in wcf service without using faultexception or fault contract.

I have searched many sites but didn't get proper answer on this.

This question has been asked in my interview.

Thanks

Comment: you can get the exact error message by setting `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>`. But generally the client has got nothing to do about it, the client might not be based out of .Net as well.Sending .Net exceptions isn't valid in those cases. `FaultContract`s notify the client with some meaningful message of what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Yes Amit that i can do to get exact message but my question is why can't we get exact error message with use of faultcontract like simple windows application where we have try and catch and will be getting exact error message, is it something serialization where without faultcontract you can't do serialization for this error message ?

Comment: `FaultContract` are meant to hide the actual error message. but provide some relevant information. Say an operation failed due to some reason. The stack trace / exception object might contain a sensitive information like credentials/credit card number or something for which these failure happened.It's not a good idea to let these information travel via network or may be reach the client. You hide those details and let the client know that the operation failed, provide a context. Exceptions are always serializable.

Comment: Thanks Amit this make some sense to me :)

Comment: I can think in two reasons: 
1) the expeption object (like ArgumentException) cannot be serializable or can be unserializable or it cannot be part of contract
2) your original exception can expose sensitive data, like database name, so it's recomended you handle the message content prior, and the right way to do it is throw a new FaultException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main reasons why we use WCF is inter-operability. An inter-operable application is one which can communicate with any application built on any other platform (say Java).

.Net Exceptions are specific to .Net. They can only be understood by a client that is also .Net. .Net exceptions can never be understood by other platforms. If you want the WCF service to be inter-operable then the service should be throwing fault exceptions.

For example there is no such exception like **ChannelTerminatedException** in Java platform. If this exception is thrown to a client which is built on Java, then this exception will never be understood by that client.

Fault exceptions allows you to create strongly typed SOAP faults. The SOAP messages generated through Faults are not specific to .Net and hence can be understood by any platform.

Fault messages are the standard to share any error information in SOAP based SOA implementations. For more information regarding the standard and the SOAP fault message structure follow: [w3.org specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383507) and [SOAP Fault Message Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189538(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Bharat for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.config`  file you can activate `serviceDebug` with :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: I can do to get exact message which I already knew anyway thanks but my question is why can't we get exact error message with use of faultcontract like simple windows application where we have try and catch and will be getting exact error message, is it something serialization where without faultcontract you can't do serialization for this error message

Comment: WCF sending a FaultException because WCF based on sop sop in and there is not the concept of exception , it is not advisable to send the exception to the client